# CakePHP3 - Drop down in forms showing years from 2022-2012

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to generate a form to add Date of Birth on submit.

This is my form.

```
echo $this->Form->input('dob', 
        array(
            'type' => 'date',
            'dateFormat' => 'MDY',
            'minYear' => date('Y')-130,
            'maxYear' => date('Y'),
            'options' => array('1','2')
            )
        );
```

For some weird reason it only shows year 2022 to 2012. Any idea why this happens?

Edited -  I want to get year 1990,1980 Etc.

Comment: So you're using CakePHP 2.0, 2.3, and 3.0?

Comment: I'm using CakePHP 3.0.

Comment: Please only use the tags that are relevant to your problem. Also please always mention your _exact_ CakePHP version (last line in `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`) - thanks! That being said, the code you are showing there works just fine for me (the `dateFormat` and `options` keys don't make sense though), `2022` to `2012` would be the default (current year +/- 5) when no custom `minYear`/`maxYear` values are being passed.

Comment: Will do. My bad sorry. How can i show a custom year? E.g 1990?

Comment: I don't know what exactly you mean by that, and how it relates to the described problem?

Comment: I want to get years before 2012. E.g - 1990,1980 and so on. I'll re edit my question.

Comment: Well, that's what the `minYear`/`maxYear` options are there for, and as mentioned, they work just fine. You'll have to come up with something reproducable (for starters the exact version number), otherwise nobody will be able to help you I'm afraid.

Comment: @drmonkeyninja Edited and fixed the version issue in the question. I tried adding minYear / maxYear but it doesn't quite work. As show above in the code snippet. Am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: @KasunWijesekara it's not clear what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to get a drop down containing every tenth year?

Comment: @KasunWijesekara Is the minYear you have set in php is different from the output you are getting?

Comment: Tested your code in Cakephp v 3.3.6 and its working great

Comment: @drmonkeyninja Aite, maybe I asked the question wrong. I'll ask it again, What I want is to show dates from minimum from 1950-2017(current) year. This is a field to add the Date Of Birth.

Comment: @AmanRawat Hello again, yes it's different I'm currently getting dates from 2022-2012. I'm trying to get at least dates from 1950-2017. This is for a Date of Birth field.

Comment: I'm not referring to the tags, please see my second comment, I'm asking for the _exact_ version number (it's in the format `major.minor.patch`), the major version isn't too helpful when it comes to isolating problems, you may for example use a specific version that has a bug, given that the code you are showing works just fine, and produces exactly the result that one would espect, ie a range from 1887 to 2017.

Comment: @ndm I'm using v3.4.5.

Comment: why you add this one  'options' => array('1','2') ? How you please explain more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this : 
I hope this will help you,

**First One :**

```
<?= $this->Form->dateTime('dob', [                            
    'minYear' => date('Y')-5,
    'maxYear' => date('Y')+5,                            
]); ?>
```

Reference from here : https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#Cake\View\Helper\FormHelper::dateTime

**Second one:**

```
<?= $this->Form->input('dob', ['type'=> 'date','dateFormat' => 'DMY',                     
                        'minYear' => date('Y')-5,
        'maxYear' => date('Y')+5,]); ?>
```

Take a look. All the best @Kasun Wijesekara.

Comment: First option works! Small edit - In my case dateTime should be just date since i only need the date. 

Thank you!